# Linkedin Authorization header with GET

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to integrate with linkedin but with `Authorization` param in the header, I followed the [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) and i'm stuck in the last step which is `Step 4 — Make authenticated requests`, I'm using JS so i don't know how to add header to `IN.API.Raw("/people/~?format=json").result(onSuccess).error(onError);`, So i tried to do it manually with `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
n_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json";
var gg = new XMLHttpRequest();
gg.open("GET", n_url, true);
gg.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
gg.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+[ACCESS_TOKEN]);
gg.send(null);
```

but this gives `OPTIONS https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json` error in the console in addition to `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, So is there any way to use IN.API that allows me to add some headers (this will be simple), Or what should i do to fix my manual request, I'm noticing that the sent request is `OPTION` not `GET`, i searched a lot about that but i didn't get a clear answer.

Any help?

Comment: If you're using client-side JS then follow [their instructions for client side JS](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) and not their generic OAuth instructions.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a **response** header, not a request header.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, excuse me if my questions is duplicated or i got less knowledge, I have my server side which need uid to login, So at first i get `code` and send it to and end-point in my server which use `code` to get an `access_token` and send it back to front-end, My idea was to use this access_token with /people/~ to get user info and send uid of the user to the server side to login, Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Step 4 of the instructions you linked to is for when you are making the HTTP request from your server-side code. You make the request directly from your server-side code. You don't make it with client-side JS and then pass the response back to your server.

Comment: It is my bad, Thank you very much.

Comment: @Amr Adel, can you please guide me how you get the access token.  I'm using JavaScript as frontend.

Comment: For sure @Sankar, Did you tried send make all the params in the url? Like `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code...` and put the rest of the params instead of ..., just don't send them as a POST request parameters as we all know, but i don't think it work from JS only you need to make your server-side call it to work ... after you get the access_token, make a call from your server side to the /people/~ too as @Quentin said, Hope this helps.

Comment: @AmrAdel can you please tell me how did you get  **code** from client side?  I just used as a link like this `<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/workout/linkedin.html&state=xxx&scope=r_basicprofile">Login</a>`

Comment: My requirement is to login from client side (JS), get the **accessToken** and send it to server for process

Comment: Actually i don't know if it going to work from your client-side but i think you should not do this because you are using your `secret_key` which is should be something private and not to be something reachable from front-end.